# perform the POST command when the user selects an option from a drop down

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am setting up a page in which the first step is for the user to make a choice from a dropdown.  I do not want to require the user to first make a selection and then click on the submit button, since there is nothing else they would be doing at this point.  Here is a code snippet from the FORM element portion of the page.

```
<form action="index.php" target="_self" method="post">
<label style:padding:1px margin:0px font-size:12px>Last Name</label>
<select name="UniqueLastNames" onchange="checkField(this.value)">
(the option values are wrapped in php and get their values from a database)
```

I know that usually the last part of this would be use the input element with type=submit, but I just want the POST action to run as soon as the user makes a choice from the list.  the Java Script 'checkFidld() returns the selected name and it currently puts it into a label on my form that just proves that the dropdown is working.

I would also prefer to use the POST as opposed to the GET so the user can not alter the url, and yes the user actually stays on the same page and the remainder of data for that page will be filled in when the page refreshes.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ Although I would caution against this, as the user may accidentally click something he didn't intend to.

Comment: If refreshing the page is fine, try submitting when on `onchange`. If you don't want to refresh the page, use AJAX and bind a function to `onchange` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call the `submit` method in your form once your `checkField` function is called. For example:

**HTML**

```
<form action="index.php" target="_self" method="post" id="your-form">
    <select name="UniqueLastNames" onchange="checkField(this.value)">
        ...
    </select>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function checkField(val) {
    // do something with your val
    document.getElementById('your-form').submit()
}
```

Please notice that I added an ID to the form element so I can select it easily in JavaScript.

Comment: This almost looks like what I am looking for.  I tested it last night and it did not seem to cause the page to refresh.  I believe there must be some issue with some of the code in the php section.  I will further test today by creating a simpler set up and let you know how it comes out.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your question and comment, you want your user to select value from drop down box and page having different fields should be update accordingly.

```
// PHP code
$choice = $_GET['userchoice'];
// Get Data from Database and update fields in Page


// In javascript, Use this code.
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkField(val)
    {
        window.location = "yourpage.html?userchoice="val;
    }
</script>
```

Again I would recommend you to use Ajax that would impact better on your clients.

Comment: Information on the page with the drop down should update based on the choice made in the drop down. And I want this page to submit when the user makes a choice, rather than having to make a choice and then click a submit button.  I am still working on Guilherme's solution, trying to figure what's is in my code between the <select and /select> that allows the onchange script to run but not allow the page to be submitted.

Comment: Well! first I would suggest you to use Ajax but that's your wish and next that the solution I suggested you is exactly what you are saying. It will refresh the page. See I have updated the Code with Comments.